# Determine the coefficients to minimalize the given integral (using trigonometrical system as basis)

Tags: functional-analysis, definite-integrals, hilbert-spaces, change-of-basis, trigonometric-integrals

The exercise is to determine coefficients a,b,c so the given integral is minimal.

I=$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|x^2-(a+b\cdot\sin(x)+c\cdot\cos(x))|^2dx$

I had the idea to look at it, as the norm of a component (lets call it $\varphi$(x)) of $L^2$([-$\pi,\pi$]), that needs to be minimalized. Hence the trigonometric system forms a complete orthonormal basis here, one should express $\varphi$(x) in this basis. However I can't really realize how to express the x$^2$ compontent in the trigonometric  basis. If someone knows the answer, please explain how this exercise can be solved. (Also I know that we can look at it with basic derivation, and search a stationary point of the function inside the integral, but I want to know the Hilbert-space solution.)

Comment: Seems as if you’re missing the point of the exercise as assigned.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by that?

Comment: You have a small trigonometric basis ($1$, $\cos x$, $\sin x$) and the point is to find $a$, $b$, and $c$ that minimize the norm. So multiply it out, do the integrations, compute the gradient with respect to $(a, b, c)$ and start solving. If you get lost, look up ''least squares approximation'' somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Mister!!

Comment: From the Hilbert space perspective you have the inner product $(e, f) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\, e(x)f(x)\,dx$. You're working with the basis $e_0(x) = 1$, $e_1(x) = \cos x$, $e_2(x) = \sin x$ and you are trying to approximate $f(x) = x^2$. Approximations are of the form 
\begin{equation*}
\varphi(x; a, b, c) = ae_0(x) + be_1(x) + ce_2(x)
\end{equation*}
and the best one, in the sense of the induced norm, is the projection of $f$ onto the space spanned by $e_0, e_1, e_2$.